# What is the exact mathematical definition of a fraction? Can all real numbers be expressed as fractions?

Tags: real-numbers, rational-numbers

As per some sources fractions have been defined as a quotient of two numbers whereas some sources restrict the numerator to be a whole number and denominator to be a positive integer.
What is the exact definition?

Comment: A fraction is not a thing at all, and a **rational number** is a whole number divided by a positive integer. Not all real numbers are rational.

Comment: A fraction is a ratio between two values.  *TECHNICALLY* those values do not have to be whole numbers.  But that usually are.  A number that can be a ratio between two whole numbers is called a rational number.  A number that *can* not be (for example $\pi$ or $\sqrt 2$) is call irrational.  We can write $\pi$ as $\frac \pi 1$ if we want and technically that is a "fraction" but it is not a ratio of *WHOLE NUMBERS*. $\pi$ is not rational and can not be written as a fraction *with whole numbers*.

Comment: @fleablood Imo this comment could (without capital letters) be an answer.

Comment: The fractions are basically pairs of integers (where the second is
non-zero) with the equivalence relation:
$(a, b) \sim (c, d)$ exactly if $a \cdot d - b \cdot c$.
See https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Rational_number.

Comment: @Loic, is there an =0 missing in your comment here?

Comment: @RedFive: Yes, $= 0$ is missing, thank you for pointing out this mistake.

Comment: Although loics comment is absolutely correct it is certainly well beyond the level of the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fraction is generally anything that can be written in the form $\frac {something}{otherthing}$ where the value is a ration between the two things, or another way of thinking about it, is one thing divided by another.  For instance $\frac 8{16}$ is the ratio of $8$ to $16$ of the value of $8\div 16$ and has the value of one-half, or if you want to use decimals (as your text obviously wants to do), the value of $0.5$.

Another example is if you take a circles circumference $C$ and it's diameter $d$ the the ratio of $C$ to $d$ or $\frac Cd$ is will always have the ratio we call $\pi$ with $\pi =\frac Cd$.  $\frac Cd$ is a fraction.  If we wanted to divide $\pi$ to a number one-fourth it's size we could write $\frac \pi 4$.

As you can see a fraction can be between any two real numbers.  We can even write a fraction as $\frac 70$ even though that is no such possible value.  It is an invalid and *wrong* fraction and can not be any possible value but it is still a fraction.  Just a wrong and useless one.

And, because $w\div 1 = w$, we can always have $w = \frac w1$ and so, yes, every real number can be a fractions.

Fractions are not a very useful concept.

....

BUT!!!

There is an entire class of real numbers called the rational numbers.  A rational number is any real value that can be written as a fraction *BETWEEN WHOLE NUMBERS*.  Or to be more precise whose numerator is an integer, and whose denominator is a positive (not zero) integer.

$\frac 8{17} = 0.470588235294117647058823529470588235294117647058823529470588235294117647058823529...$ is are rational number because $8$ and $17$ are integers.  But $\frac \pi 4$ is *not* because $\pi$ is not an integer. And there is no way we can change the values and make it a fraction between whole numbers.

Rational (and irrational) numbers are a *very* important concept.

Answer (score 1):

*A fraction (from Latin: fractus, "broken") represents a part of a whole* - Wikipedia

More simply, a fraction is a notation. Let's say there are 5 apples. You have eaten 3. A way of expressing this statement is that *$\frac{3}{5}$ of the 5 apples have been consumed*.

A form of a fraction which can be used for operations is known as a rational number. By definition, a rational number is a number which can be represented by $\frac{p}{q}$ where $q≠0$ and $p,q∈Z$. The fraction $\frac{3}{5}$ can be represented as a rational number. But all fractions cannot be represented as rational numbers

A good example includes this. You have a square of area 4 $m^2$. You cut out a circle of radius 1 m it. The area of the circle will be $π m^2$. So the area of your circle is $\frac{π}{4}$ times the total area of the square.

But $\frac{π}{4}$ is not a rational number, as π is an irrational number and cannot be expressed as $\frac{p}{q}.$

Like π, other irrational numbers like $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}$ cannot be expressed as rational numbers.

Fractions can never be negative as well.

**PS:- A Fraction is a notation. You cannot express a real value as a fraction, but as a rational number or irrational number.**